# Remove leading zeros from a number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parseint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truncate leading zeros of a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594325/truncate-leading-zeros-of-a-string-in-javascript)

What is the simplest and cross-browser compatible way to remove leading zeros from a number in Javascript ?

e.g. If I have a textbox value as 014 or 065, it should only return 14 or 65

Comment: What for? Do you want to format the text in the field or do you just want to get the correct decimal value? `parseInt` takes a second parameter, the radix, which should always be set! Set it to `10`.

Comment: @felix. you already typed this as a comment :) +1 for that unary `+` didn't think of it.

Answer (score 310, accepted):

We can use four methods for this conversion

1. [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Javascript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) `10`
2. [Number Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Constructor)
3. [Unary Plus Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)
4. Using mathematical functions (subtraction)

```js
const numString = "065";

//parseInt with radix=10
let number = parseInt(numString, 10);
console.log(number);

// Number constructor
number = Number(numString);
console.log(number);

// unary plus operator
number = +numString;
console.log(number);

// conversion using mathematical function (subtraction)
number = numString - 0;
console.log(number);
```

---

#### Update(based on comments): Why doesn't this work on "large numbers"?

For the primitive type `Number`, the safest max value is **2<sup>53-1</sup>**([`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)).

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

Now, lets consider the number string *'099999999999999999999'* and try to convert it using the above methods

```js
const numString = '099999999999999999999';

let parsedNumber = parseInt(numString, 10);
console.log(`parseInt(radix=10) result: ${parsedNumber}`);

parsedNumber = Number(numString);
console.log(`Number conversion result: ${parsedNumber}`);

parsedNumber = +numString;
console.log(`Appending Unary plus operator result: ${parsedNumber}`);

parsedNumber = numString - 0;
console.log(`Subtracting zero conversion result: ${parsedNumber}`);
```

*All results will be  incorrect.*

That's because, when converted, the numString value is greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. i.e.,

```
99999999999999999999 > 9007199254740991
```

This means all operation performed with the assumption that the `string`can be converted to `number` type fails.

For numbers greater than **2<sup>53</sup>**, primitive [`BigInt`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-bigint-objects) has been added recently. Check browser compatibility of `BigInt`[here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=bigint).

The conversion code will be like this.

```
const numString = '099999999999999999999';
const number = BigInt(numString);
```

---

#### P.S: Why radix is important for `parseInt`?

If radix is undefined or 0 (or absent), JavaScript assumes the following:

- If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X", radix is 16 (hexadecimal) and the remainder of the string is parsed
- If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal)
- If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal)

Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent. ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet.

For this reason, **always specify a radix when using parseInt**

Comment: It isn't clear from the question if it's ever the case, but this also removes anything after the decimal point.

Comment: parseInt("08") == 0, it's a bug, use another answer.

Comment: @Greg. Thanks for the info. But I did not get the relevance. `parseInt("08", 10)` is indeed `8`

Comment: might want to mention that the radix is important, so that people don't make the same mistake as greg.

Comment: Heads up to anyone using this solution: Make sure you use the second parameter. parseInt("08") == 0, whereas parseInt("08",10) == 10

Comment: This won't work for large numbers represented as strings.

Comment: numbers that exceed int values right?

Comment: Ok then try to parseInt some string with large number:
parseInt('099999999999999999999');  // It may lead to really big issues and bugs that hard to find

Comment: @Roman updated the answer on why it doesn't work on large numbers

Comment: parseInt("0", 10) = 0. So if if by "remove leading zeros" you want an empty string in this case, you'll need to handle it explicitly.

Comment: Note that parseInt will throw away any decimals in the initial value. `parseInt("0123.02", 10) === 123`

Answer (score 255):

regexp:

```
"014".replace(/^0+/, '')
```

Comment: best solution, if you have a string like 012A (street number) this is the way to go. ty

Comment: bad thing is it turns "0" into "" when the user would probably want to keep that one zero.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson : for that negative lookahead canbe used`replace(/^(?!0$)0+/, '')`

Comment: @PranavCBalan that is good, but what if the user inputs something like 00 or 000 and so on ?

Comment: @Devid :  for that, much more simple one using positive look-ahead assertion `replace(/^0+(?=\d)/, '')`

Answer (score 26):

It is not clear why you want to do this. If you want to get the correct numerical value, you could use [unary `+` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2b_%28Unary_Plus%29):

```
value = +value;
```

If you just want to format the text, then regex could be better. It depends on the values you are dealing with I'd say. If you only have integers, then

```
input.value = +input.value;
```

is fine as well. Of course it also works for float values, but depending on how many digits you have after the point, converting it to a number and back to a string could (at least for displaying) remove some.

Comment: For some reasons, this is not working...See http://jsfiddle.net/8pYXH/

Comment: @hmthr: You did not assign a string to `x`, but a number. With a leading zero it will be interpreted as octal value. Print `x` and you will see that this value is already `13`. Using a string works: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/8pYXH/1/

Comment: So finally will it still be a string ...I want the final value should be an integer...

Comment: @hmthr: No. The value you get from field will be a string. After applying unary `+` it will be a number (as it is written in the documentation). See: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/8pYXH/3/