# Replace leading 0 on input field

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to replace the leading zero from a input field.

I am trying this but getting no luck

```
var regex = replace(/^0+/, "");
```

Comment: You need to add the string where you want to replace it in. `"01234".replace(/^0+/,"")`

Comment: Is replace a partial?

Comment: If you want to remove the leading zeroes there might be [better ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676488/remove-leading-zeros-in-javascript).

Comment: You didn't provide the input field...!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a string in your example.  Try something like this:

```
var foo = '012345';
var bar = foo.replace(/^0+/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct try using like this:

```
$ele.val(function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/^0+/, "");//sets the value of each element to the original value without 0 padding
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$("field_id").val($("field_id").val().replace(/^0+/, ""));
```

or this:

```
$("field_id").val(function(i, val){ return val.replace(/^0+/, ""); });
```