# Prevent inputting leading 0

Tags: javascript, validation, zero

I can input

**0** but not **0123**. How do I prevent users not to input 0 at the first position of the input text field?

Comment: Allow the zero, but trim it prior to using the value.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6676488

Comment: Have you consider using `<input type="number">`? The advantage would be that you whould have access to `input.valueAsNumber` in most browsers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let them input it, just trim it when focus changes:

```
inputElement.onblur = function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/^0+(?=\d)/,'');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t56c1o76/3/)

Note that it's specifically looking for a digit (`\d`) after the 0's that it's nuking, so it won't touch the zero in something like `0.123`.  If you want to get rid of those, too, just change the `\d` to `.`, which matches any character whatsoever.

Comment: thanks for your answer but what I wanted is to prevent the user, like onkeypress. Is there a way?

Comment: There's a way to do almost anything. :) In this case it would be more complicated code and probably more confusing for the user, though.

Comment: I have to agree with you on that! Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to check the first character in the input using `charAt()`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/m8xum79u/2/)

JS:

```
function check(){
    var number = document.getElementById('input').value;
    if(number.charAt(0) === 0)
        alert('Leading zero in the input.')
    else
        alert('No leading zero in the input.')
}
```

**EASIER SOLUTION:**

For the input, just check the first character like an array:

```
if(number[0] === '0')
        // do something
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/m8xum79u/3/)