# How to rearrange date string from MM DD YYYY to YYYY MM DD?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, date-fns

I tried `new Date(03/11/2015)` but it didn't work but `new Date(2015/3/11)` does. How do I convert a string like '03/11/2015' to '2015/3/11'? I tried using `date-fns` with the `format` method but `format(new Date(03/15/2015), 'YYYY/MM/DD')` returns `Invalid time value`

Why isn't the `Date` constructor taking in string values in MM/DD/YYYY format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex replacement approach here:

```js
var input = '03/11/2015';
var output = input.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/, "$3/$1/$2");
var date = new Date(output);
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the leading zeros as well in a single regex? i.e. from 03 to 3 without another replace like replaceAll("^0+", "")

Comment: @JaeLeeSo Please see [this canonical JavaScript answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676488/remove-leading-zeros-from-a-number-in-javascript).