# javascript remove leading zeros from a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, octal

```
const a = 043      
console.log(Number(a))
```

Here the variable a is octal because of which we get the result as 35.
Instead, I want the variable a to be a number 43.
Found results for removing leading zeros from a string([Remove leading zeros from a number in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676488/remove-leading-zeros-from-a-number-in-javascript))

Comment: You can't do it. If it's not a string, the number is parsed by the compiler, your code never sees the original representation.

Comment: `043` is an _octal_ literal, not the number `43` with a zero in front of it.

Comment: `043` _is_ `35`. There is no zero to remove.

Comment: Anyway, why can't you just **not** put the 0 in front of 43?

Comment: I have written a function to which the input(I get from Excel) can also be a number with leading zeros(like 043)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your value starts with 0, and its type is number instead of string, it will be recognized as octal, and when you use it directly, javascript will convert it to decimal

The fastest way you can use [Number.prototype.toString(radix)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp)

```js
let a = 043
console.log(a.toString(8))
```