# remove values from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how I would remove all leading zeros from a string.

```
var str = 000890
```

The string value changes all the time so I need it to be able to remove all 0s before a number greater than 0. So in the example above it needs to remove the first three 0s. So the result would be 890

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var resultString = str.replace(/^[0]+/g,"");
```

Comment: sorry about that... apparently we think alike.

Comment: @Anders no worries - smart people tend to think alike :)

Comment: Luck of the draw, congrats ;)

Comment: The square braces are optional. The global flag is unnecessary, since only one "beginning of a string" can exist. The following pattern will do: `/^0+/`.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like we each have our own ways of doing this.  I've created a test on [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/leading-zero-removal), but the results are showing

```
String(Number('000890'));
```

is the quickest (on google chrome).

[image]

---

Here are the numbers for [the updated test](http://jsperf.com/leading-zero-removal/2) based on @BenLee's comment for Firefox, IE, and Chrome.

[image]

Comment: For my Chrome 16 (for Linux), I am getting much closer performance for options 2 and 3 than you are (my results are regex: 5mm, classes: 17mm, parseInt: 15mm, typecasting: 22mm)

Comment: Oh, I should mention I'm the one that added the 4th test for `'' + +str`, which turns out to actually be the fastest contender, outperforming the next fastest by about 50% and outperforming the slowest by a factor of 5.

Answer (score 5):

See: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594325/truncate-leading-zeros-of-a-string-in-javascript)

```
var resultString = str.replace(/^[0]+/g,"");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a function like this should work

```
   function replacezeros(text){    
      var newText = text.replace(/^[0]+/g,"");
      return newText;
}
```

Comment: new i would get beaten to the punch on this one

Answer (score 2):

If it needs to stay as a string, cast it to a number, and cast it back to a string:

```
var num = '000123';
num = String(Number(num));
console.log(num);
```

You could also use the shorthand `num = ''+(+num);`. Although, I find the first form to be more readable.

Comment: +1 for simultaneously posting what I think is the cleanest-looking solution `String(Number(num))` as well as what turns out to be the fastest-peforming solution `''+(+num)` (see JesseB's answer for confirmation on that)

Answer (score 2):

If your problem really is as you defined it, then go with one of the regex-based answers others have posted.

If the problem is just that you have a zero-padded integer in your string and need to manipulate the integer value without the zero-padding, you can just convert it to an integer like this:

```
parseInt("000890", 10) # => 890
```

Note that the result here is the integer `890` not the string `"890"`. Also note that the radix 10 is required here because the string starts with a zero.

Answer (score 2):

```
parseInt('00890', 10); // returns 890
// or
Number('00890'); // returns 890
```

Answer (score 1):

`return str.replace(/^0+(.)/, '$1'));`

That is: replace maximum number of leading zeros followed by any single character (which won't be a zero), with that single character.  This is necessary so as not to swallow up a single "0"

Answer (score -1):

you can simply do that removing the quotation marks.

```
var str = 000890;
//890
var str = "000890";
//000890
```