# Javascript - Leading zero to a number converting the number to some different number. not getting why this happening?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A leading zero to some number converting the number to some unknown number format.
for example :

`017` is getting converted to `15`

`037` is getting converted to `31`

Also found that numbers having 8 0r 9 at end are remaining same
for example :

`018` is `18`

`038` is `38`

`o59` is `59`

one more thing that I found is

for each next range of 10 the difference between converted value and the actual value get incremented by 2

for example :

for range  `00-09`  difference is  `0`  i.e  value of 07 will be 7, 04 will be 4

for range  `010-019`  difference is  `2`  value of 017 will be 15, 013 will be 11

for range  `020-029`  difference is  `4`  value of 027 will be 23, 021 will be 17

and so on..

here is a snipet for test http://jsfiddle.net/rajubera/BxQHF/

I am not getting why this is happening ?

Please help me  how to get the correct decimal number from the number having leading zero ?

Comment: You're going to need to post some code so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leading zero in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505033/leading-zero-in-javascript) and [Javascript, why treated as octal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071696/javascript-why-treated-as-octal)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript parseInt() with leading zeros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763396/javascript-parseint-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: no in my case parseInt(012,10) doesn't help. you can check the jsfiddle link

Comment: *Why* are you writing your numbers with leading zeros? If you want decimal values, just don't do that. If you are getting the values as string input, `parseInt(string,10)` will work (but you are correct that using `parseInt` on an octal literal will not convert it to decimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there is a leading 0, it is converting it to octal (base 8) as long as its a valid number in base 8 (no numbers greater than 7).

For example:

`017` in base 8 is 1 * 8 + 7 = 15
`037` in base 8 is 3 * 8 + 7 = 31

`018` is converted to `18` because `018` isn't a valid number in base 8

Note that the behavior as to which base the number is converted to by default can be browser-specific, so its important to always specify the base/radix when using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

`parseInt("017",10) === 17`

UPDATE based on comments:

`parseInt` expects a `string` as the first argument, so

`parseInt("012",10) === 12`

Comment: Fixed: base 8 if its a valid base 8 number, otherwise base 10. Thanks!

Comment: if it was converting to octal base then 018 should return 16 but 018 is resulting to 18.

Comment: I also think so..but then how can I get the correct number ??

Comment: Use parseInt(yourNumber,10) to get the correct value if your numbers are in base 10.

Comment: thanks but 
no in my case parseInt(012,10) doesn't help. please check the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/rajubera/BxQHF/

Comment: yes but is there any way that I can convert the number to string before passing to parseInt function.
as when I am doing either of ''+012 or 012.toString() it's returning me "10" that means first the number is getting converted then getting stringified.

Comment: As @apsillers pointed out in his comment, why are these numbers with leading zeroes to begin with?  If they are coming from user input they should probably be starting out as strings, and if they aren't then they just shouldn't have leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons to `"use strict";`

```
(function() {"use strict"; 017})()

// Firefox => SyntaxError: "0"-prefixed octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated; for octal literals use the \"0o\" prefix instead 
// Chrome, Node => SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal