# Understanding implicit conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I hunted down a bothersome JavaScript error where I was passing one argument, but when it was received, it was something completely different. I fixed it, but would like to know what was happening for future reference.

What I should have passed as an argument is '0616' (with quotes).  What I actually passed was 0616 (without the quotes).

So, when it was received, some kind of implicit numeric conversion took place, and it was received as 398.  I understand implicit and explicit conversion, but WHAT was happening to turn 0616 into 398.  The leading zero seems to have something to do with it because other values that I passed that were non-zero in the most significant digit survived just fine.  It's only those that begin with zero?

But what relation is there between 398 and '0616' ?

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071696/javascript-why-treated-as-octal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason is that the leading zero is javascript notation for base octal, e.g. 010 = 8. The notation for hexadecimal is a leading 0x, e.g. 0x10 = 16

Answer (score 5):

Ahh the magical world of javascript!!

Any numeric literal that starts with a 0 is treated as an octal number.

A hacky workaround is

```
parseInt('0616', 10)
```

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, but I think `parseInt('0616', 10)` would be safer, in case he still have to support some old browsers, which have interpretation for octal.

Answer (score 3):

`0616` is the old octal number format. In new spec it should be `0o616`, however the old format is still supported by browsers.

See this [**wiki page**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#In_computers):

> prefix 0o was introduced to .... and it is **intended to be supported by ECMAScript 6** (the prefix 0 has been discouraged in ECMAScript 3 and dropped in ECMAScript 5).