# JavaScript charAt() doesn't like user input that isn't zero

Tags: javascript, html

this may be a stupid question or a typo but I'm going to ask anyway... I have the following form and when the form is submitted I want to check all the values of the `input type="number"` and make sure that if the user has for some reason put a zero at the start of the input, for example 01, 025, 0100, to remove the first zero as long as the value isn't zero. A simple piece of JavaScript made even easier with a jQuery selector. Note that all the text boxes here are `type="number"` not `type="text"` and please note my input

[image]

Here's my code:

```
$('input[type=number]').each(function(){
    // only if the string is not zero
    if(this.value.charAt(0) == "0" && this.value != "0"){
        this.value = this.value.substring(1);
    }   
});
```

However when I came back to test my form fully I noticed my code didn't work! So I added the following to write to the console to check what was going on:

`console.log("typeof:" + typeof(this.value) + " " + this.id + " char:" + this.value.charAt(0) + " val:" + this.value )`

And this gave me the following output, notice the last 4 items that don't have the value of zero:

[image]

Why am I not getting the `this.value.charAt(0)` when the user has changed the default value of zero?

Comment: could it be that there are spaces in the input?

Comment: @nyarlathotep: put that as an answer and I'll plus one you. The output shows spaces between "val:" and "04" (as an example in the last one).

Comment: @nyarlathotep: put that as an answer

Comment: yup, definitely a leading space problem.

Comment: As a side comment does your code deal with multiple zeros? At a glance it looks like an input of "001" would be trimmed to "01" which is presumably not what is wanted...

Comment: @Chris good suggestion, added an according handling of arbitrary zeroes to my solution!

Comment: I just want to add that I was unaware of the white space. This is being produced by jquery.mobile?!?! The target device for this app is a tablet, I'm just debugging/testing in Firefox on my laptop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that there are spaces in your value. Trim it before comparing (e.g. with [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), or [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498970/how-do-i-trim-a-string-in-javascript) if you don't want to include jquery just for that):

```
$('input[type=number]').each(function(){
    // only if the string is not zero
    var myval = $.trim(this.value);
    this.value = myval.replace(/^[0]+/g,"");

});
```

The above solution removes arbitrary leading zeroes, that part was taken from [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1265228/671366).

Answer (score 3):

This can be cut down somewhat:

```
$('input[type=number]').each(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^\s*0+(?=\d)/, '');
});
```

That will remove any leading zeros, even if there's leading white space (which is probably your problem).

Comment: neat and clean, I like it :) but I'd put in a + after 0 to make it also remove multiple leading zeroes!

Comment: also didn't know yet about the lookaheads, something learned again :D!

Comment: Yeap - no lookbehinds in JS, though, which is massively annoying, although [I wrote a simulation for this](http://mitya.co.uk/blog/2011/Feb/Simulating-REGEX-look-behinds-JavaScript-153). Good point re: multiple leading zeros - edited.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like for some reason there is preceding whitespace - use jQuery's trim function before your zero-check to ensure you've eliminated the whitespace.