# Replacing if the first number is a zero and the number is greater than 2 places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a calculator I'm working on and came across a problem. To combat so that users can't leave a field blank, I'm forcing a zero if the field is left empty. That's all fine, but the problem is that when the text in the field is deleted to remove the zero and enter a new number, it automatically enters zero so my new number looks like this: 05

How do i run a replace where if there is more than 2 places in the number and the first number is zero, replace the zero? Here's the code i'm using for my calculator.

```
$(function(){

  calculate();

$('.input').keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
               return false;
    }
   });

  $('.input').on('keyup',function(){
    if($(this).val()==''){
      $(this).val('0');
    }
    calculate();
  });

});

function calculate(){

  var d6 = parseFloat(($('#d6').val()).replace(/,/g,''));
  var d20 = parseFloat(($('#d20').val()).replace(/,/g,''));
  var b20 = d6;
  var e20 = parseFloat(($('#e20').val()).replace(/,/g,''));

  var f20 = d20*e20;
  var f22 = b20/f20;
  var f23 = (52-f22)*f20;

  $('#f20').html(formatCurrency(f20));
  $('#f22').html(f22.toFixed(2));
  $('#f23').html(formatCurrency(f23));

}

function formatCurrency(x) {
    return '$'+x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Comment: if(str.length > 1 && str[0] == "0") {
    str=str.substring(1,str.length)
}

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594325/truncate-leading-zeros-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @juvian the second check is unnecessary I think. According to what he said the 0 is always being prepended.

Comment: @Onilol if you check the code, he changes '' to '0', so after a while the .val() will be '12', without a 0

Comment: OP are you using a html form for this or.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are essentially trying to turn it into a formatted number you could try type coercion:

```
'' + new Number('')       // "0"
'' + new Number('0')      // "0"
'' + new Number('05')     // "5"
'' + new Number('0000.2') // "0.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the zeroing code to use the blur() event, i.e when the field loses focus.

`$('.input').blur(function(){

       if($(this).val()=='')
       { 
            $(this).val('0'); 
        }
});`

Comment: I don't think this is what he asked.

Comment: This should fix his problem as the keyup event will enter a zero when the user inputs into an empty field

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the text is removed from pressing the backspace key.

If that is the case then you keyup handler would fire when you backspace on the zero, which would detect no input, then add the zero.

Comment: Or it could be highlighted and replaced with another key.

Comment: Either way, it will be adding an unintended zero via the handler.

Comment: I think they are different things , @PhilipRead . As you said, the backspace on keyup detects no input, but highlighting and replacing with another value would detect input.

Comment: That's true. Didn't really think about that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are doing it a hard way. And try this... if the user clicks on the input then it will be cleared and the user can write whatever number he wants...

```
$( ".input" ).focus(function() {
  (this).val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using keyup and keypress event for checking and replacing blank to zero, use change event.

```
$(function(){

  calculate();

$('.input').keypress(function (e) {
     //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
     if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
               return false;
    }
   });

  $('.input').on('keyup',function(){
    calculate();
  });

$('.input').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val()==''){
      $(this).val('0');
    }
  });

});

function calculate(){
var d6Val = ($('#d6').val() !== "")? $('#d6').val() : '0';
var d20Val = ($('#d20').val() !== "")? $('#d20').val() : '0';
var e20Val = ($('#e20').val() !== "")? $('#e20').val() : '0';
  var d6 = parseFloat((d6Val).replace(/,/g,''));
  var d20 = parseFloat((d20Val).replace(/,/g,''));
  var b20 = d6;
  var e20 = parseFloat((e20Val).replace(/,/g,''));

  var f20 = d20*e20;
  var f22 = b20/f20;
  var f23 = (52-f22)*f20;

  $('#f20').html(formatCurrency(f20));
  $('#f22').html(f22.toFixed(2));
  $('#f23').html(formatCurrency(f23));

}

function formatCurrency(x) {
    return '$'+x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

One more thing. Change event only fires when you focus-out from that input.

Please let me know if you will face any issue.

Comment: This actually worked. Didn't think of doing that. Thanks!

Comment: Just realized that this actually breaks the calculator in that now it's not doing calculations in real-time. I now have to change to another field in order to get a result. Any other ideas?

Comment: Damien are you using a html form ?

Comment: Try this: '' + new Number($(this).val())

Comment: Hey Damien can you share the HTML structure so that i can use your code and do some testing.

Comment: I just update the solution. May be now this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using an HTML5 form you can avoid that piece of code like this:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Type a number" required>
```

The required attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out.