# Unpad number from a padded number

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I know how to run a script to generate and pad a number but I do not know how to unpad them.
For example, 0008 means that there are 4 padding but the value of the padded number is 8.

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num + "";
    while (s.length < size)
        s = "0" + s;
    return s;
} 

pad(8, 4);
```

However, how do I unpad them?
Let's say I have a 0011 and I want to unpad the numbers to log only 11.
Is there a solution for this?If I use the slice method then it will not work if the padded number is 0100 or 1000.

Comment: Use `parseInt()` way to get the unpad value. As simple as that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove leading zeros from a number in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676488/remove-leading-zeros-from-a-number-in-javascript)

Comment: Or of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594325/truncate-leading-zeros-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt()` to the padded value to get unpad value. If you expect to have a `string` result for unpad values then you can use `toSting()` on the parsed value.

```js
function pad(num, size) {
  var s = num + "";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
} 

var padded = pad(8, 4);
console.log('padded '+padded);
var unpad = parseInt(padded);
console.log('unpad '+unpad);


padded = pad(100, 4);
console.log('padded '+padded);
unpad = parseInt(padded);
console.log('unpad '+unpad);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now use `padStart()` method for padding and `+` for unpadding. for example:

```
const x = "8";
const padded = x.padStart(4, 0);
console.log(padded) // "0008"
const unpadded = +x;
console.log(unpadded) // 8
```

Hope it could help anyone to get a code much cleaner.

Comment: Great answer. Very clean and easy to un-pad numbers.